# Por que foi usado o DIV e por que foi atribuído um ID?

Tags: css, front-end, div, id

Fazendo um exercício criando uma pagina usando HTML e CSS fiz da seguinte forma e ficou igual no modelo proposto pelo professor. Porém, o prof e os demais alunos fizeram de uma forma diferente usando a tag div e um id com atributos.

Por que mesmo deixando de usar o div e o id minha pagina ficou igual ao modelo e quando devemos usar o div ? abaixo meu css, meu código e o do professor.

```
body{background-color: #2c3e50;}

.text-red{color: red;}

#dias-da-semana {color: yellow;}

li{color: white;}

h1{color: white;}

h2{background-color: yellow; 
border: 2px black  solid;}
```

```html
ESTE É MEU CÓDIGO


<body>
    <h1>Treinamento para Astronautas</h1>
    <h3 id="dias-da-semana">Dias da Semana</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Segunda</li>
      <li>Terça</li>
      <li>Quarta</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Segunda</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Usando um texto qualquer</li>
      <li>Usando um texto qualquer</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Terça</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Este texto é exemplo</li>
      <li class="text-red">Este texto é exemplo</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Quarta</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Exemplo de texto</li>
      <li class="text-red">Exemplo de texto</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
  
  DO PROFESSOR:
  
  
  body>
  <h1>Treinamento para astronautas</h1>
  <div id="days-of-week">
    <h3>Dias da semana</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Segunda</li>
      <li>Terça</li>
      <li>Quarta</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="activities">
    <h2>Segunda</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Condicionamento cardiorrespiratório</li>
      <li>Aula de mecânica</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Terça</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Treinamento em gravidade zero</li>
      <li id="astronomy-class">Aula sobre astronomia</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Quarta</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Aula sobre coleta de material científico</li>
      <li id="astronomy-class">Aula sobre astronomia</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

A ideia de usar divs consiste em você poder organizar blocos de código, neste exemplo pode funcionar muito bem, mas imagine em um exemplo aonde você quer posicionar blocos de código em ordems especificas ou fazer partes do site separadas, o uso da div serve pra isso, é como se você criasse um pedaço do quebra cabeça e encaixasse aonde vc quer